# Cool android image view

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an photo gallery app for android. I would like to make a similar flash-like image view like the one found on this site http://www.ideas.singtel.com/appmanager/ideas/web?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=web_homepage . This will be nice for user interactivity....

how can i do it to a similar quality or what should i research on?

Kind regards

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [huge tutorial to make a coverflow widge](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)[t for Android](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html). I think you can customize this to give a rolodex look that you want.

> CoverFlowExample simply extends Activity and instantiates a Coverflow class in it's onCreate method. It also has an internal Class, ImageAdapter which we use as the adapter for the Coverflow widget, much as we would for a Gallery widget

Comment: Thanks .Just checked it out and yeah.. definitely what I want. If I get any barriers when customizing  it I will given U a shout .Thanks again